# How to make ALB to redirect traffic and not create another instance?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I have nodejs application with route that makes a calculation that takes a long long time. and take 100% from the thread. like fibonacci function.

```
app.get('/long', (req, res) => {
  console.log('in long');
  function fibonacci(n) {
    return n < 1 ? 0 : n <= 2 ? 1 : fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
  }

  const x = fibonacci(2000);
  console.log('after x');
  res.json({ x });
});
```

The ALB health check for `/` if it response with 200|300|301 status code.

When its not, then aws create another instance and remove the unresponsive instance.

This case is a problem because I lose the currect request which complete sometime. I don't want to restart the application again if the request is taking too long. the app is still running.

Any way to configure this behavior? just to redirect the traffic to available instance?

Comment: An autoscaling group behind an ALB *might* handle this the way you want, but in a fairly expensive fashion if you traffic pattern is not constant.  This seems like a really good use-case for Lambda or another serverless architecture where you can easily scale the thread count to meet demand and not have to pay for idle resources.

Comment: @JonSud Based on what you are saying, the system is working exactly as intended. If the Health Check fails, then the instance is automatically replaced. If you think it should _not_ be replaced, then you should investigate why the Health Check is failing. You could direct the health check to an alternate page that returns immediately, rather than a page that takes a long time to process. If that is not possible, then you might want to totally remove the Health Check since it cannot reliably detect a good vs failed instance.